# _.groupBy dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm working with this data structure, and trying to produce a total object for (patApplied & insApplied) keys.

I'm confused about using `_.groupBy` on patApplied and insApplied when working with key names that are dynamic (they might change based on user selection).

I'm trying to groupBy map / reduce the values to match desired `total` object

```
[
  {
    procedure: '01402',
    fee: 82.08,
    patApplied: {
      'Credit Adjustment': 20,
      'User payment': 30
    },
    insApplied: {
      insPayment: 5,
      'ins check': 10
    }
  },
  {
    procedure: '01801',
    fee: 165.16,
    patApplied: {
      'Credit Adjustment': 0,
      'User payment': 10
    },
    insApplied: {
      insPayment: 0,
      'ins check': 7
    }
  }
]
```

desired output

```
let total = {
  patApplied: [ {Credit Adjustment: 20},{User payment: 40} ]
  insApplied: [ {insPayment: 10},{ins check: 7} ]
}
```

Comment: Why `insPayment` is `10` it should be `5`.

Comment: And also `ins check` should be 17, not 7, right?

Comment: @Mihai its a pre sudo code, and you are right! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the objects by spreading into `_.mergeWith()` and then extract the properties you want with `_.pick()`:

```js
const data = [{"procedure":"01402","fee":82.08,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":20,"User payment":30},"insApplied":{"insPayment":5,"ins check":10}},{"procedure":"01801","fee":165.16,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":0,"User payment":10},"insApplied":{"insPayment":0,"ins check":7}}]

const result = _.pick(
  _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (obj, src) => _.isNumber(obj) ? obj + src : undefined)
, ['patApplied', 'insApplied'])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And a terser version of the same solution using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and `_.flow()`:

```js
const { flow, mergeAllWith, cond, isNumber, add, pick } = _

const fn = _.flow(
  mergeAllWith(cond([[isNumber, add]])),
  pick(['patApplied', 'insApplied'])
)

const data = [{"procedure":"01402","fee":82.08,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":20,"User payment":30},"insApplied":{"insPayment":5,"ins check":10}},{"procedure":"01801","fee":165.16,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":0,"User payment":10},"insApplied":{"insPayment":0,"ins check":7}}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `for..in`.

```js
const arr = [{"procedure":"01402","fee":82.08,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":20,"User payment":30},"insApplied":{"insPayment":5,"ins check":10}},{"procedure":"01801","fee":165.16,"patApplied":{"Credit Adjustment":0,"User payment":10},"insApplied":{"insPayment":0,"ins check":7}}]



let total = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  ['patApplied','insApplied'].forEach(k => {
    for(let key in a[k]){
      ac[k][key] = ac[k][key] || 0;
      ac[k][key] += a[k][key]
      
    }
  })
  return ac;
},{patApplied:{},insApplied:{}})


console.log(total);
```

Comment: I think this answer is simpler than the first answer